# Pyenv unable to install older versions of Python 3 due to `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, openssl, pyenv

I've been trying to use `pyenv` to install older versions of python3. I've tried `3.0.1`, `3.1.0`, `3.1.1`, and `3.1.2`. I kept getting the error

```
ImportError: No module named _ssl
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

Following some documentation from pyenv I tried updating my command to explicitly pass the location of the headers and libraries like so:

```
➜ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/bin/openssl/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/bin/openssl/lib" \
pyenv install -v 3.1.2
```

That seems to have gotten past that error but now I'm getting the error `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

The only suggestion I can find for Ubuntu is to install/update the `build-essential` package which I've done and was already installed and fully updated.

I can see that the `gcc` command is working. So what else am I missing?

### Full Error

```bash
➜ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/bin/openssl/include" \  
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/bin/openssl/lib" \
pyenv install -v 3.1.2
/tmp/python-build.20230107155624.97473 ~/GitProjects/VWAP_backtest
Downloading Python-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.2/Python-3.1.2.tgz
/tmp/python-build.20230107155624.97473/Python-3.1.2 /tmp/python-build.20230107155624.97473 ~/GitProjects/VWAP_backtest
Installing Python-3.1.2...
patching file ./setup.py
patching file ./Lib/ssl.py
patching file ./Modules/_ssl.c
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux5
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 2.3.9-18-g25c974d5)
```

Comment: Have you tried examining `config.log` to see exactly why gcc is failing?

Comment: Trying, can't tell where this `config.log` is saved. Just tried to find it and got find: `‘config.log’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `libssl-dev` package is missing. Try installing that library along with some others you might have missed by using the [pyenv build instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment).

In particular you should install the pyenv dependencies. For example for the Debian OS you would want:

```bash
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl llvm \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

Comment: unfortunately still getting the same error :'(

Comment: can you use a docker container with an older version of Ubuntu and then install python?